# Blender orthographic camera setting exactly same as a Unity camera

Tags: camera, unity, orthographic

I'm trying to set a blender camera like a Unity camera. when I tried perspective type, it worked perfectly. But when trying orthographic type, there's different result by a camera view. I can't control Blender camera scale exactly same as Unity.
Is there anything way?

Comment: Does using the Orthographic scale setting under the camera properties not work or is it that the values that blender uses are too different compared to unity to line up properly?